# Partitioned RelativeLayout has left RelativeLayout overlapping right RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

*Note: this may appear to be a repeat question, however I have no found one to answer my question/provide a solution.*

I have a layout which I **would like** to have designed as follows:

[image]

**This is what I have attempted so far:**

Current layout design:

[image]

The corresponding (*attempted*) XML layout is found below (*with a problem*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/layout_details">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subscriptionCost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="$ 0.00"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currency"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/subscriptionCost"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="(USD)"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subscriptionDuration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="2 Year Subscription"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subscriptionMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/subscriptionDuration"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Oon until Jaunarasdasddasdasd asd asdasdda sdasd asda sd as da sd as da sd a sd as d as d as d asdasdasday 2020"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

*I think the layout I am trying to achieve is obvious, but I will explain nontheless.*

The layout is to provide an overview of subscriptions offered in my app.

- The subscription duration on the top left, with further details (which can be multilined) below the duration.
- The price of the subscription on the top right, and below the currency which the price is in.

**The problem**

I have 2 `RelativeLayout`s as left and right layouts. The Left layout should be able to scale according to screen size while the right layout should remain as `wrap_content` width.

Having the current right `RelativeLayout` and children as `wrap_content`, it appears that the left RelativeLayout simply overlaps and forces the right layout below, even with `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` being set.

I am not sure what is causing the problem, but any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use Nested `RelativeLayout` for this

You can do using single `RelativeLayout`

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subscriptionDuration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/subscriptionCost"
        android:text="2 Year Subscription"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subscriptionCost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="$ 0.00"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textSize="24sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subscriptionMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/subscriptionDuration"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/currency"
        android:text="Oon until Jaunarasdasddasdasd asd asdasdda sdasd asda sd as da sd as da sd a sd as d as d as d asdasdasday 2020"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currency"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/subscriptionCost"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="(USD)"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Sure I could, but then I have the misaligned Price and currency and the message text will overlap the price constraints. That is why I specifically chose the duo `RelativeLayout`, as this does not look very attractive.

Comment: @KGCybeX didn't get u can u explain more and what is your expected output

Answer (score 0):

Hi after some checks i would advise you to use ConstraintLayout:
here full code which match you requirements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">


  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/subscriptionDuration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="2 Year Subscription"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <TextView

    android:id="@+id/subscriptionMessage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/subscriptionDuration"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Oon until Jaunarasdasddasdasd asd asdasdda sdasd asda sd as da sd as da sd a sd as d as d as d asdasdasday 2020"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/currency"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subscriptionDuration" />


  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/subscriptionCost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="$ 0.00"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/subscriptionDuration" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/currency"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/subscriptionCost"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="(USD)"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subscriptionCost" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You sure about this? It will simply override the `wrap_content` and `match_parent`. It had no effect on my layout.